# UIButton embedded in cell.accessoryVIew not responding

Tags: uitableview, uibutton

I am using a "Dynamic Prototypes" `UITableview` for which I am generating the table cell as follows

```
-(UITableViewCell*)populateFeatureCell:(UITableView*)tableView row:(NSUInteger)row {

    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FeatureCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    SKProduct *product = [STLNavigatorIAPHelper productAtIndex:row];
    if (product != nil) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [product localizedTitle];
        UIButton *buyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        buyButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 72, 37);
        [buyButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"BUY", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        buyButton.tag = row;
        [buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
         cell.accessoryView = buyButton;
    }

    [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    return cell;
}
```

I am able to see the cell in the table but the cell does not respond to any events. Please note the function `buyButtonTapped` has been defined as well.

Answer (score 0):

The table row for at index path is getting the first hit.

You can process in there or pass in along to button.